# Java httpservlet and routing. How starting?

Tags: java, web-services, servlets

my boss asked me to develop an webservice that should work in this matter:
an external app contact my app and:
if the method used is GET and the url contacted is:
http://localhost:8080/webapp/webservice/?findall
will return all rows find in a table;

If the same external app contact my app in the same method but send a key and a value like:
http://localhost:8080/webapp/webservice/?field1=value1

my app will return a set of rows filtered by field/value.
And soon on with with any method sending request and with other fields.

I know how do the operations using JPA 2.1 but how mapping the actions?
Someone could help me to starting in the right direction with JDK1.8?

Comment: I'm reading the two tutorial posted by @andres and, for now, I'm studing SPRING because: 1) it use jdk 1.8; 2) it returns a json object (it was a second passage of my final web app).

Comment: Maybe you want to start with [Oracle Java EE tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/)?

Comment: @Serge Ballesta  : thanks for your suggestion but, as you know, it is very big and I would know something more specific :-)